# Extremely Simple Bibliography Not Working

Tags: bibliographies

I've created a simple LaTeX file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

My bibliography.bib file is in my main working directory and looks like this

```
@book{1,
    author = {Bill Bezio},
    title = {Numerical Simulations},
    date = {August 2016},
}
```

When I build and view the pdf in TexStudio (OS is Ubuntu 16.04) I get one page with the word "References" at the top and nothing else. There is a footer of "1" at the bottom but no references. Where are the references?

Comment: Also, welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've actually made any cited references, so LaTeX isn't going to just add everything to your bibliography.  Use `\nocite{1}` to instruct LaTeX to add citekey `1` to your bibliography even if it's not used in your document.  You could use `*` instead to put *everything* from your `.bib` file into your bibliography, but your `.bib` file could easily grow beyond what you're using for this paper.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{1,
    author = {Bill Bezio},
    title = {Numerical Simulations},
    year = 2016,
    month = August,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\nocite{1} % <---

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. Any reason the date is not showing up?

Comment: @sixsigmar Edited. Looks like the `plain` style doesn't include the month, but `date` was never a key to begin with.

Comment: I think you forgot the curly brackets around the month and the year. When I put those in it works exactly the way I want :)

Comment: @sixsigmar Ah, that makes more sense :) I could've sworn `date` was valid, but I wasn't getting it working and I wasn't finding it in the manuals… I'm out of practice!

Comment: Final question. I just read the forum etiquette and I'm supposed to put @Sean Allred. I put that but it's not showing up. I guess the reason is there's a space between your first and last name. How do I "@" you when there's a space in your userID?

Comment: You can ask on meta if you have more questions, but my name would only show up if I would not be notified otherwise. Since this is a comment on my question, I'm going to be notified regardless. You can try pinging me as a comment on your own question if you'd like to try it out.